# Append data columnwise in C/C++

Tags: c++, c, file-handling

I want to add columns of data to a text file, one column in each iteration (one space between each column). If I open file for appending, it adds next column at the bottom of first column. Is it possible to append *sideways*?

All data isn't available at the start. Only one column of data becomes available in each iteration, and it gets lost in the next iteration.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the file to be one long stream of characters, some of them just happen to be line breaks. Append always starts at the end of the file. If I'm reading you right you need to use seekp(seek new position to put new characters at) on your fstream to get to the right position before writing.

You know the format of your file, therefore you can calculate how much to skip in each line.

Something like this might work:

```
 read line
 while line != "":
     skip forward the right number of " "
     write new column
     read new line
```